# Accessing Master Page and Nested Master Page Properties from Content Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, master-pages

How do I access master page properties and a nested master page properties from a content page?  I currently use <%@ MasterType in my content page to access properties of the nested master page, but I don't think I can simply specify another mastertype to get to the master page.  Or, can I?  (IIS6, .Net4, c#).

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: You are using ASP.NET WebForms, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can access a master page by [Page.Master](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master.aspx) property

**Important:** ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master.aspx))

> 1. The Master property returns the MasterPage object associated with this
>      page. This property is read-only; however, you can set properties on
>      the MasterPage object it returns.
> 2. The Master property is valid only on pages that reference a master
>      page in the MasterPageFile property. If you access the Master property
>      on a page that does not reference a master page, null is returned. The
>      contents of a master page are not available until after the PreInit
>      event has been raised.

Comment: Thanks.  I got that.  What I mean is that I have nested master pages.  Each master page (the "main" one and the nested one) has public properties.  I need to be able to set both in my content page.  I can set the properties of the nested page using Master.NestedMasterProperty=x; in my code-behind file.  But, how can I do the same for properties in the "main" master page.

Comment: Smth like var mainMasterPage = Page.Master;
            while (mainMasterPage !=null && mainMasterPage.Master != null)
            {
                mainMasterPage = mainMasterPage.Master;
            }

Comment: Thanks.  The Master.Master.property was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @user984599 : Welcome to StackOverflow! If any particular answer are really answered your question you can mark this by accepting an answer. This will help an other visitors, but if you do not sure that answer is correct do not accept it to avoid confusing of an other users